# Web content doesn't fit webview's frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uikit

I'm using a `UIWebView` to display a mobile website on my `iPhone`. The `UiWebView` is smaller than the display of the iPhone.

My Problem is that the content size of the website (a mobile website based on JQuery mobile) doen't fit the size of the web view.

Just an example with a small web view trying to display the google mobile website:

[image]

```
NSString *urlAdress = @"http://google.de";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAdress];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:request];
[webView sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Please user this Java script [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document. body.style.zoom = 5.0;"];

Comment: Also dont forget to set scalesPageToFit to NO and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

**Primarily** : set the `delegate` to the WebView

> In **.h** file

```
@interface WebViewViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

> In  **.m** file

```
webView.delegate =self;

webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;

NSString *urlAdress = @"http://google.de";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAdress];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 1):

add these to your code for your webview :

```
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```